# Use a Firefox bookmarklet to fire a mouse click on an element?

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, onclick, bookmarklet

I'm trying to use a Firefox bookmarklet to fire an onclick event in an asp.net based web form, without physically clicking on the element. The URL of the page doesn't change no matter where I navigate on the site. Even if I could use document.getElementById("id").click(); that would be fine.

So far I have this code that I'm using in a bookmarklet

```
javascript: document.getElementById("ticket").click();
```

It doesn't work. I can get it to work on elements with link id's but not elements with td id's. To my understanding, it doesn't work since it's a td id I'm working with and not a button/input/link id.
Here's the element's code:

```
< td id="ticket" class="menu" nowrap="" align="center" onmouseout="this.className=this.className.replace(' highlighted', '')" onmouseover="this.className=this.className + ' highlighted'" onclick="menuClick('ticket', null, ''); ">
```

Any suggestions on how to fire a mouse click on that element (using a bookmarklet)? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just call that method? `menuClick('ticket', null, '');`

Comment: So would my code look like this then?:
        javascript: call({menuClick('ticket', null, '');})       
Sorry I'm a bit of a novice at writing code.

Comment: Where did you invent that call({}) code?

Comment: I got it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/h2ak8h2y%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: My javascript skills are pretty weak but I'm learning.

Comment: That is not how you use call(), It should just be `javascript:menuClick('ticket', null, '');void 0;`

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I got it to work with javascript:parent.menu.menuClick('ticket');

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Your problem may be the space between '<' and 'td'.